# Tap on disabled TabBarItem

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have `TabBarItem`, which is disabled. I want to show alert, if user tap on it.

But this function doesn't work:

```
override func tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar, didSelectItem item: UITabBarItem) {
        if item.enabled == false {
            self.presentViewController(defaultAlert, animated: true){}
        }
    }
```

When I change `if item.enabled` to `true`, alert is shown. As I understand correctly iOS don't receive taps on disabled tab bars. Can I change this behavior?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Yes that's correct, when it is disabled it doesn't receive the tap. You will need to keep it enabled and track it being disabled another way

Comment: Instead of disabling, maybe just pop up an alert when it would be disabled and hide everything that you don't want to show in that view controller. Then, when the user taps to dismiss the alert you bring up, it segues back to another view.

Comment: Looks like, this is the only solution. I thought it can be done with less code ((

Answer (score 0):

Not the best but another option is to add a UIButton over the top of the disabled UITabBarItem which would pick up the touch and allow you to show the alert even when the tab bar item is disabled.

You will need to subclass the UITabBarViewController and create the button in there at the correct tab position.